# Double clicking on WPF datagrid WITH RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have searched and searched and found no answer.
I have a datagrid which utilizes the RowDetailsTemplate to display some higher-level information about that particular row.  However, when the user double clicks on a row, I would like to display a separate form which displays much more detailed information.
How can I accomplish this?

I forgot to mention: On double click, I want to open the detail WITHOUT seeing the row details template! – Menashe 1 hour ago

Thanks!

Menashe

Comment: Can you post a watered down version of a RowDetailsTemplate in XAML?  That we we can just post it in our IDE and try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this together and it seemed to work... I added a MouseDown handler to the grid in the RowDetailsTemplate:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"  >
                    <TextBlock >This</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
       //Open the window here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this.  But I forgot to mention: On double click, I want to open the detail WITHOUT seeing the row details template!